# Which software do I need for complete online banking protection?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, security, anti-virus

I have Norton (Symantec) antivirus software on my system and have also installed Rapport after recently starting to use online banking.

Do I need both systems for complete protection?

Answer (score 0):

Anti-phishing, misdirection and scraping. Sounds like a good idea, but still make all the effort you can to keep your computer clean. It isn't clear how much use it is if you aren't with [one of the banks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapport_%28software%29).

Answer (score 0):

Trusteer is the leader in this technology.

Rapport is the program.

http://www.trusteer.com/webform/download-rapport

Answer (score -1):

Online banking is safe regardless of whether or not you download two antivirus systems. The banking industry invests millions of dollars into consumer protection software. Not only is online banking MA safe to use but at some community banks, it is entirely free.